# What is the difference between "eb push" and "git aws.push"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When using the Amazon Web Services (AWS) Elastic Beanstalk command line interface, what is the difference between

```
eb push
```

and

```
git aws.push
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3, they are essentially the same, as `eb push` ultimately runs `git aws.push`

source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk/cli/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3.zip